# How to edit the appearance of QFileDialog in PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5

I want to know how to edit the appearance of QFileDialog with the "DontUseNativeDialog" option (this first picture) into the native appearance (the second picture). Like the label of the buttons and other styles.

I need a QFileDialog allow the user to select multiple directories. I find the solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252419/how-to-get-qfiledialog-to-select-and-return-multiple-folders) but the appearance changed.

Picture 1: not native dialog

[image: Picture 1: not native dialog]

Picture 2: native dialog

[image: Picture 2: native dialog]

Comment: Are those screenshot taken from the same system? Are you using some custom styling (`setStyle()` or `setStyleSheet()`)?

Comment: Those screenshot taken from the same system. For the first one, I use "file_dialog.setOption(QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog, True)". I think the first one was implemented in PyQt so that I can setSelectionMode and the second one was implemented in Windows SDK (I guess, because most the file selection dialog in other program is the same style) so I can not edit anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.

Use `dialog.exec()` or `dialog.open(accept_function)` instead of `dialog.show()`. The latter shows an old-school style dialog for some reason.